# x86 instructions, define value

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to know how can I solve this task in assembly, I know it is basic question but I don't know anything about assembly and can't start learning for just understanding this task problem is that I don't know which part should I start to read and so on
so could you please let me know step by step way to solution?
I know the answer: 400
but way to answer is important for me

question:
The following x86 instructions are written in assembly language. Define the
value of register eax:
1: xor eax, eax
2: xor ebx, ebx
3: xor edx, edx
4: mov eax, 64h
5: mov ebx, 28h
6: div ebx
7: mov eax, edx
8: mul edx
The answer must be written in decimal notation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: "can't start learning" ... well, reading any answers would be learning. Anyway, you should at least get an instruction set reference so you can look up what the four instructions that appear in this code do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1: xor eax, eax 
eax = 0
2: xor ebx, ebx 
ebx = 0
3: xor edx, edx 
edx = 0
4: mov eax, 64h 
eax = 100
5: mov ebx, 28h 
ebx = 40
6: div ebx 
eax = (100 / 40) = 2
edx = (100 % 40) = 20
7: mov eax, edx 
eax = edx
8: mul edx 
edx:eax = (edx * eax) = (20 * 20) = 400
```

```
auto n = (100 % 40)
return (n * n)
```

[div](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html)
[mul](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_210.html)

Comment: `div` is integer division, EAX is an integer register.  The exact quotient of 2.5 truncates to `EAX = 2`.

Comment: Ya, my mistake, i had initially setup everything as floating point and forgot to fix that one when I did for everything else. It's late. :)

Comment: Also, since you're showing both results of `div`, don't forget that `mul` also writes EDX with the high half of the multiply result.  If this code wasn't intentionally obfuscated, they'd just use `imul eax,edx` (or avoid the `mov` and just `imul edx,edx`).  2-operand `imul` is faster than 1-operand `mul` and is the standard way to multiply in 32 and 64-bit code.

Comment: Well I did but I just used ``edx:eax`` instead of writing them separately like I did for div. Mainly this is because the values are known and the result fits in 4 bytes. Obfuscation aside, optimization should make it a simple ``return 400``. This isn't obfuscation though, probably some problem from a text book. Normally I wouldn't give an answer like this but it's so simple and hopefully breaking it down like that helps OP more than simply referring him to the instruction references.

Comment: Oh, my bad, that's fine, I just missed that you listed it that way.  (I think mostly I wanted to complain about the code being dumb, not your answer.  Obviously the whole thing is pointless with constant inputs vs. `mov eax,400` / `xor edx,edx`.)  And yeah, it's obviously some kind of student problem to teach them about the implicit operands of `div` and `mul`, not to use an efficient multiply instruction.